# How to put Objects from one map to another?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a `Map` like this :

```
Map<String,GridCell> cellsMap
```

I pass this into a method and the return from that method should contain a `Map`(say `answerMap`) which contains all the entries of `cellsMap` map **plus an extra entry** that contains a `String` as the key and a `String` as the value . Something like :

```
  Map<String,Object> answerMap  = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object>();
    //answer should first contain all the map entries of cellsMap and then add an extra entry like the following
    answer.put(getId(), getSelectionValue()); // getSelectionValue() returns a String that contains coordinates of the selected cells.
     return answerMap;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered the [Map.putAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method ?

e.g.

```
answerMap.putAll(cellsMap);
```

I don't think this is a good object model, by the way. I think you're better off creating a new class that contains your original map (maybe a copy) and an additional field for your `String`/`String` pair.

Otherwise you're throwing objects of different types into the same map, and that's going to make life complicated when you later extract that info. Each time you extract via a key you're going to have to check the type of the object returned. Note that `ConcurrentHashMaps` don't maintain insertion order.

Comment: Why does answerMap.putAll() allow us then if it is a danger ? backward compatibilty for raw types?

Comment: putAll() isn't the problem. It's a simple way of populating one map from another. My issue is that you're using a map to store different unrelated types (GridCell and String), so when you do a get(), you don't know what you're getting

Answer (score 0):

Use clone() method.

```
HashMap answerMap = (HashMap)cellsMap.clone();
```

Comment: As far as I know it is not allowed to cast `Map<String,GridCell>` to `Map<String,Object>`. So this will probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

Map interface has putall() method which add all values of another object in Map.